# How to initialize the key in the bucket parameters for AWS S3

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm trying to figure out how to put an object in S3 by following the [SDK documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js/). I have placed the credentials in `~/.aws/credentials`, but it's not clear how I can obtain the access key from the stored credentials. Is there an aws-sdk call to get the key from `~/.aws/credentials`?

```
var myKey = 'myBucketKey'; // <--- aws-sdk to get the key from the credentials file?
```

Comment: have you tried making any s3 operation? As I understood it, the SDK will take it from there for you, you just put it in the file

Comment: @JChrist I have not, but in the bucket parameters `Key` is labeled as required in the aws-sdk documentation,  my presumption was that it wouldn't work "automagically." :)

Comment: I'll run it in a bit and I'll se if it's working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Key` of an object stored in Amazon S3 is a reference to the **filename**. It has nothing to do with access credentials (that use an **Access Key** and **Secret Key**).

It is called a Key because Amazon S3 is effectively a large Key/Value store, where the Key is the name of the file and the value is the content of the file.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the quick answer.